# Scope was not available. Did you forget to call container.BeginScope()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, castle-windsor, castle

Hello I want to using castle windosr in .net core and I have get bellow error in .net core:

> Scope was not available. Did you forget to call
>   container.BeginScope()?

my code is :

```
         public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        //container.BeginScope();
        Bootstrapper.WireUp(container);
        FrameworkBootstrapper.WireUp(container);
        var configureServices = WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider(container, services);
        return configureServices;
    }
```

I added the error image .
[image: full image for error]

in your option if i add `container.BeginScope();` after `var container = new WindsorContainer();` Is it the right way? Is there any problem?
WindsorRegistrationHelper is a package between .net core built in ioc and castle
you can see on below link:
https://github.com/volosoft/castle-windsor-ms-adapter

Comment: at which line does this exception is thrown?

Comment: above code on ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs
but error only show after ConfigureServices and  Configure  The problem comes after their Invoke.

Comment: Mind to show a more complete example? When exactly does it happen? Before `Configure` is call or during an web request? This message is usually an indicator that you try to resolve a scoped (or transient) service from a an application wide controller (effectively making the scoped/transient service a singleton)

Comment: On the first look it seems that Windsor is a .NET Core IoC non-conformer. The [docs](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/aspnetcore-facility.md) suggest you need to use the `services.AddWindsor(Container,..., ...)` call instead which will also register the activators for controller, views components and tag helper

Comment: Could you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: I edited the post.
I used a package called Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection Adapter

Comment: @JanMuncinsky I edited post I added the error image

Comment: What is `Bootstrapper.WireUp`, `FrameworkBootstrapper.WireUp` and `WindsorRegistrationHelper.CreateServiceProvider`. Could not reproduce them without them. Share us a complete example.